# Is parsley root with pink spots safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, mold, parsley

Today I peeled a parsley root for soup and discovered it has red/pink spots all over it.
It did not look unusual before peeling. I bought it in a supermarket about a week ago, five pieces packaged in plastic together, and kept it in fridge since.

I know that parsley root is rarely spotless, but the amount of spots on this one surprised me. Otherwise it smells and feels just like parsley root.

**Is it safe to eat? Is it some kind of mold or other disease that's better to throw away?**

[image: peeled parsley root with pink spots]

**`EDIT`**
Today (one day later) I peeled another parsley root from the same package (the unpeeled one in the picture above) and it seems fine, with no signs of pink whatsoever.

One more thing: According to the text on the packaging the parsley was grown in Czechia, which is where I am.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41348-018-0200-6) is an abstract of a paper called ***Erwinia persicina* associated with a pink rot of parsley root in Germany**

This contains the following text fragment:

> may be latently contaminated with both E. persicina and Pectobacterium
> carotovorum subsp. carotovorum. The latter in particular might be part
> of a complex of factors **leading to the distinctively severe symptoms
> observed**.

(Bolding added by me.)

I don't think I'd eat it myself; I might even report it to the place I bought it - they should know that they have been supplied bad food so that they can do something about it, hopefully.

Added: I'n not actually sure whether the 'severe symptoms' apply to the root itself, or to possible consumers of it. Take a bet?)

Comment: +1 for finding it, and posting here. But you don't have to take a bet on the "severe symptoms" sentence - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwinia, this is a plant pathogen.

Comment: @rumtscho - sure, but that WP page includes Salmonella as one of the family. Salmonella may be a plant pathogen, but it's also a human pathogen! The rest of the family may actually be innocent, but it's still a bet, I'm afraid.....

Comment: nice find, thanks! the mentioned paper includes pictures of the infected roots and rather than pink dots it shows a continuous pink discoloration of about half of the root. but it might be a related disease.